# Unable to add or see notes on list

Tags: java, android, sqlite, notepad

**Project Description**: I'm creating an android application where I want to add notes to the schedule of my study.
I based my notepad on this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html - Notepadv3Solution
I've added to the database column "p_id" - this is the id of the subject that was clicked. I want to use this id later.

**Problem**: The notes aren't being added. Or maybe they are being added but don't display. I have no errors in the console.

**Code**:

NotatkiActivity.java - class with list of notes

```
package pack.organizer;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NotatkiActivity extends ListActivity {
private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;

private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;

Intent myIntent;
long idp;

private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notatki);        

    myIntent= getIntent(); 
    idp = Long.valueOf(myIntent.getStringExtra("id_p"));         

    mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();
    fillData();
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}

private void fillData() {
    //myIntent= getIntent(); 
    //String idp = myIntent.getStringExtra("id_p");  

    Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(notesCursor);

    // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
    String[] from = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE, NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY};

    // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2};

    // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, notesCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, "Dodaj notatkę");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case INSERT_ID:
            createNote();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, "Usuń notatkę");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case DELETE_ID:
            AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            mDbHelper.deleteNote(info.id);
            fillData();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

private void createNote() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteEdit.class);
    i.putExtra("idprzedmiotu", idp);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    myIntent = getIntent(); 
    idp = Long.valueOf(myIntent.getStringExtra("id_p")); 
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteEdit.class);
    i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
    //i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_PRZEDMIOTID, id_p);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    fillData();
}
}
```

NoteEdit.java

```
package pack.organizer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NoteEdit extends Activity {

private EditText mTitleText;
private EditText mBodyText;
private Long mRowId;
private Long mpId;
private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;
private Bundle bundle;
Intent myIntent;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();

    setContentView(R.layout.note_edit);
    setTitle("Edytuj notatkę");

    mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
    mBodyText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.body);

    Button confirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);

    mRowId = (savedInstanceState == null) ? null : (Long) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);

    if (mRowId == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID) : null;
    }


    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    mpId = bundle.getLong("idprzedmiotu");        
    populateFields();

    confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
        }

    });
}

private void populateFields() {
    if (mRowId != null) {
        Cursor note = mDbHelper.fetchNote(mRowId);
        if( note != null && note.moveToFirst()){
            startManagingCursor(note);
            mTitleText.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
            mBodyText.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY)));
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    saveState();
    outState.putSerializable(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveState();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    populateFields();
}

private void saveState() {
    String title = mTitleText.getText().toString();
    String body = mBodyText.getText().toString(); 
    if (mRowId == null) {
        long id = mDbHelper.createNote(title, body, mpId);
        if (id > 0) {
            mRowId = id;
        }
    } else {
        mDbHelper.updateNote(mRowId, mpId, title, body);
    }   
}

}
```

NotesDbAdapter.java

```
package pack.organizer;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class NotesDbAdapter {

public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static final String KEY_BODY = "body";
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_PRZEDMIOTID = "p_id";

private static final String TAG = "NotesDbAdapter";
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

/**
 * Database creation sql statement
 */
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table notes (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "p_id integer not null, title text not null, body text not null);";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "notes";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

private final Context mCtx;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

/**
 * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
 * opened/created
 * 
 * @param ctx the Context within which to work
 */
public NotesDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}

/**
 * Open the notes database. If it cannot be opened, try to create a new
 * instance of the database. If it cannot be created, throw an exception to
 * signal the failure
 * 
 * @return this (self reference, allowing this to be chained in an
 *         initialization call)
 * @throws SQLException if the database could be neither opened or created
 */
public NotesDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    mDbHelper.close();
}


/**
 * Create a new note using the title and body provided. If the note is
 * successfully created return the new rowId for that note, otherwise return
 * a -1 to indicate failure.
 * 
 * @param title the title of the note
 * @param body the body of the note
 * @return rowId or -1 if failed
 */
public long createNote(String title, String body, long p_id) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, body);
    initialValues.put(KEY_PRZEDMIOTID, p_id);

    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

/**
 * Delete the note with the given rowId
 * 
 * @param rowId id of note to delete
 * @return true if deleted, false otherwise
 */
public boolean deleteNote(long rowId) {

    return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

/**
 * Return a Cursor over the list of all notes in the database
 * 
 * @return Cursor over all notes
 */
public Cursor fetchAllNotes() {

    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_PRZEDMIOTID, KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_BODY}, null, null, null, null, null);
}

/**
 * Return a Cursor positioned at the note that matches the given rowId
 * 
 * @param rowId id of note to retrieve
 * @return Cursor positioned to matching note, if found
 * @throws SQLException if note could not be found/retrieved
 */
public Cursor fetchNote(long rowId) throws SQLException {

    Cursor mCursor =

        mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_PRZEDMIOTID, 
                KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}

/**
 * Update the note using the details provided. The note to be updated is
 * specified using the rowId, and it is altered to use the title and body
 * values passed in
 * 
 * @param rowId id of note to update
 * @param title value to set note title to
 * @param body value to set note body to
 * @return true if the note was successfully updated, false otherwise
 */
public boolean updateNote(long rowId, long p_id, String title, String body) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    args.put(KEY_BODY, body);
    args.put(KEY_PRZEDMIOTID, p_id);

    return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own notepad instead of using full source code from internet ...it will give you step by step solution and it is better for your programming dude :) please don't take it as wrong way my friend :)